# How to set ConstraintLayout constraints programmatically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, programmatically-created

I have CardView and ConstraintLayout with size changing in code. I want to constraint CardView to this layout in code. 
I tried dif. ways :

```
   val params= wikibtn.layoutParams as  ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
   params.bottomToBottom = R.id.wiki_layout
   params.endToEnd = R.id.wiki_layout
   wikibtn.requestLayout()
   wikiL.requestLayout()
```

and this :

```
   val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
   constraintSet.clone(wikiL)
   constraintSet.connect(R.id.wiki, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.wiki_layout, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0)

   constraintSet.applyTo(wikiL)
```

None of them have worked:(  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error, CardView does no change its location as should